# In PHP, how to add a line to a file without loading it?

Tags: php, file, memory, io, ram

I have a few very large text files that weigh over 1GB and I constantly need to add a line to the top / beginning of the file with PHP.

I know how to do this but what is the most efficient way in doing this in terms of memory usage?

Comment: invert the problem and add the line to the end..?

Comment: That's a tough problem, see [Need to write at beginning of file with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760525/need-to-write-at-beginning-of-file-with-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only add to a file efficiently at the bottom. If you need to add to the top you have no other option but to rewrite the entire file.

The way to do this without reading the entire file into a buffer is to move data back in chunks until you have free space at the top.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach (if you are using a *nix platform) would be to use have PHP make system calls to cat and file redirection which would be far more efficient in terms of memory usage and performance than trying to manipulate the file header w/ PHP.