# input-button to textarea and writingorder

Tags: php, javascript, textarea

I'm stuck making a simple chat-function.
There are two problems i have with my code:

1. I want the new posts to appear on top in the textfile.
2. I want the input-buttons to write some html-code to the textarea, to make it easier to formate the text on use.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
forma1 = "<B>   </B>"
forma2 = "<font color="#B2E0B2">        </font>"
forma3 = "<font color="#C2E0FF">        </font>"
forma4 = "<font color="#FFC2C2">        </font>"
</script>

    <form method="post">
<div align="center">
  <input name="navn" type="text" size="30" style="color:#68748D;" value="Navn" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Navn') this.value = '';"/>
    <input type="button" onkeypress="form1('area');"/>
    <input type="button" onkeypress="form2('area');"/>
    <input type="button" onkeypress="form3('area');"/>
    <input type="button" onkeypress="form4('area');"/>
  <br>
  <textarea name="txt" cols="55" rows="5" id="area"></textarea>
  <br><br> <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" class="a" />
</div>
  <?php
  if ( isset( $_POST[ 'submit' ] ) ) {
    $dude  = $_POST ['navn'];
    $time = gmdate("M d Y H:i:s",time()+(2*60*60));
    $com  = $_POST['txt'];
    $fp = $file = fopen( "msgs.txt", "a");
    fwrite($file, $time);
    fwrite($file, "<br>");
    fwrite($file, '<font color="#68748D" style="font-weight:800;" size="+2">');
    fwrite($file, $dude);
    fwrite($file, '</font>');
    fwrite($file, "<br>");
    fwrite($file, $com);
    fwrite($file, "<br>________________________________________________________________________<br>" );
    fclose($fp);
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location ="";</script>';
  }
  ?>

  <br>
</form>
<font><b><p>Output: </p></b></font>
<fontcolor="#000" size="2">
  <?php
  if (file_exists("msgs.txt")) {
  $file = fopen( "msgs.txt", "r" );
  echo fread( $file, filesize( "msgs.txt" ) );
  fclose( $file );
  }
  ?>
</font>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hey buddy i cant understand the problem here, its more like your giving requirements:). tell me whats not working ?

Comment: hello :) i want those input-buttons to add some written code to the text area.
Also i would like the new text to come on top in the msgs.txt-file instead for on the bottom, like it does now.

Comment: can u simulate the same on jsfiddle, i`ll check it

Comment: try using $fp = $file = fopen( "msgs.txt", "c"); here when we replace "a" by "c" it opens file and keeps file pointer at beginning of the file, so every content you write will be placed at the top of the file.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KPXq4/

Err, seems like there is more bugs in my script.
Hope it's not a problem

Comment: $fp = $file = fopen( "msgs.txt", "c" ); didn't do the trick :\

Comment: try fseek($fp, 0); will move file pointer at begining before using fwrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer the write to the beginning of a file with [Need to write at beginning of file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760525/need-to-write-at-beginning-of-file-with-php):

```
$file_data = "Stuff you want to add\n";
$file_data .= file_get_contents('msgs.txt');
fwrite('msgs.txt', $file_data);
```

The php manual stated that fwrite and file_put_contents are identical so this should still work