# fwrite to front of file for my chatroom with php and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, fwrite, chatroom

I have a simple chatroom I've built. I actually want it to scroll up instead of down, meaning new messages are added to the top of the chat. This means I have to fwrite to the top of the file. I have done a lot of trial and error, as well as googling and overflowing, but haven't had success. Also, I understand that I need to use r+ likely, and not a, but I wanted to give the currently functional code, not the under construction code.

The two commented out lines are two ideas I tried. r+ continuously replaced the first line, and left text. If I typed 1 character, it left >r>>, if I typed 2 characters, it left >r>, if I typed 3 characters, it left r>, if I typed 4, it left >, and if I typed 5 or more, it left nothing.

I can't find much relevant information to this. Perhaps I'm using the wrong keywords. Please help me understand.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
$text = $_POST['text'];

$fp = fopen("log.html", 'a');
//$fp = fopen("log.html", 'r+');
//fseek("log.html", 0)
fwrite($fp, "<center><div class='msgln'><b>".$_SESSION['name'].":</b>      ".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."<br></div><br></center>");
fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760525/need-to-write-at-beginning-of-file-with-php

Comment: Adding data to the beginning of the file requires rewriting the entire file.  Otherwise you are just overwrite data that is already there.

Comment: You might also look at storing this in some sort of MySQL (or other type of) database so that you can control the order it appears in.

Comment: How much slower will using a rewrite of the entire file each time be compared to moving the data to MySQL?

Comment: It depends on how much data you are expecting to write and read.

Comment: Just a chatroom log, never longer than a few hundred lines

Comment: I would for sure move it to a database. I had a chatroom app that I wrote to a DB using AJAX and long-polling to get near live time updates to the users and no one ever noticed any lag.

Answer (score 0):

A - Use a database. This is a poor implementation.

B - If you insist on using this implementation, Writing the beginning of a file resets the pointer and overwrites the file. Instead, grab data from current file, add it to new data, and rewrite the file.

C - There will be collision issues. Don't actually do this. But it will work.

Try:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['name'], $_POST['text'])){
$text = $_POST['text'];
$current_content = file_get_contents("log.html");
$new_content = "<center><div class='msgln'><b>".$_SESSION['name'].":</b>      ".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."<br></div><br></center>".$current_content;
file_put_contents("log.html", $new_content);
}
```