# fwrite sort by date (latest high up)

Tags: php, sorting, fwrite

I've tried to make a comment system, by using fwrite() code. It works but I want my latest comments to list on top of the list.

Here is my code which works but it doesn't work the way I want. Latest comments appears under the list :((

```
<?php
if ($_POST){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$content = $_POST['commentcontent'];
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$handle = fopen("comments.html","a");
fwrite($handle,"<b>" . $name . "<b> (" .$date . ") </b>" ."</b>:</br>" . $content . "</br>");
fclose($handle);

}
?>


<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
Comments: <textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="commentcontent"/></textarea></br>
Name: <input type="text" name="name"></br>
<input type="submit" value="post!"></br>

<?php include"comments.html";?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: similar post is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760525/need-to-write-at-beginning-of-file-with-php

Comment: if you create **"comments.html"** date wise, then you can use php's **"c+"** file open mode to append to the starting of the file, else you have to write a lot of code for sorting.

Comment: c+ removes the previous post :((