# File getting truncated when it's not supposed to

Tags: php

I have the following php script.

```
<?php

create_time_stamp('time_stamp_file.txt');

function create_time_stamp($fname)
{
    $fh = fopen($fname, 'c+');
    if (!$fh) {
        die ('Could not open date stamp file');
    }
    $time = time();
    $time_array = array(
        'epochtime' => $time,
        'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time)
    );
    fwrite($fh, json_encode($time_array)."\r\n");
}
```

time_stamp_file.txt had the follwoing in it:

```
{"epochtime":1482524298,"date":"2016-12-23 20:18:18"}
```

When I ran the script, I was expdecting to see the following in it:

```
{"epochtime":1482524540,"date":"2016-12-23 20:22:20"}
{"epochtime":1482524298,"date":"2016-12-23 20:18:18"}
```

Instead, it only had a single line:

```
{"epochtime":1482524540,"date":"2016-12-23 20:22:20"}
```

I thought that c+ means, place the pointer at the beginning of the file, do not truncate it, and open it for read/write. Any ideas?

NOTE: Yes, I can read the file into a buffer, add the data to the beginning, and write it back out to the file, but my question was about the use the c+ flag.

Comment: same thing for me on 5.6, use `a+` to append

Comment: shall I quote the manual also? http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: *"I thought that c+ means, place the pointer at the beginning of the file"* - that doesn't append to a file. You should read the manual on this thoroughly.

Comment: [Need to write at beginning of file with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760525/need-to-write-at-beginning-of-file-with-php) --- [How do I prepend file to beginning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332262/how-do-i-prepend-file-to-beginning) seeing that comment below.

Comment: I have delete the answer as it's not relevant ( I misunderstood the question).
The link @Fred-ii- provided has a good memory-efficient answer.
But its time efficiency is bad with the file growing large.

I advice for appending to the end of the file and read the last n lines ..

Answer (score 0):

just write fread($fh,filesize('time_stamp_file.txt')) after you open it (read the file once), it will work as expected.