# How to add new data to the top of .txt without deleting in PHP

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, fclose

When I use this codes

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
```

It overwrites the text. I want the old data too at footer. so, how to add new data to the top of .txt without deleting in PHP

> Possible output.txt and view

```
(new) line8
(new) line7
(new) line6
(old) line5
(old) line4
(old) line3
(old) line2
(old) line1
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760525/need-to-write-at-beginning-of-file-with-php

Comment: You can always read the data before and do a concatenation to $data no? :|

Comment: this will be painful when file size gets bigger

Comment: @marmeladze any solution if size bigger

Comment: `<?php $cmd1 = "echo 'Lorem ipsum' > some.txt"; $cmd2 = "cat some.txt big.txt > new.txt";shell_exec($cmd1);shell_exec($cmd2); ?>` -)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$txt = "col1 col2 col3 coln";
file_put_contents('data.txt', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Please, try this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may try to concatenate data you wish to add with the data in the 'data.txt' file.

```
$data = "(new) line\n";
file_put_contents("data.txt", $data . file_get_contents("data.txt"));
```

Answer (score 1):

> you can use from PHP DOC [file get contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [file put contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$newdata = "4- whatever you need \n";
$datafromfile = file_get_contents("data.inc.txt");
file_put_contents("data.inc.txt", $newdata.$datafromfile);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to open the file with the 'a' mode instead of 'w'.

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a');
```

From the php manual: [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

> 'w'   Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.
>
> 'a'   Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. In this mode, fseek() has no effect, writes are always appended.