# How generate .php files that refer to the same head.php file?

Tags: php, html, include

Here is what I have so far

```
file_put_contents('./'. $dir .'/'. file .'.php','<?php include "../head.php"; echo $head; ?>' . $body);
```

I also tried

```
file_put_contents('./'. $dir .'/'. file .'.php','<?php include "../head.php"; ?>' . $body);
```

and then `echo $head;` in the /head.php

I want a head.php that is called by each of the generated files. There for I need to insert the php code `<?php include "../head.php"; ?>` on top of the files.
with the given code `<?php include "../head.php"; ?>` it shows ï»¿ on top.

head.php

```
echo '<html>...';
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
...
```

The issue is, it shows ï»¿.
I don't think this is a dupe.

Comment: you want to add a line to the top of a file?

Comment: that's right, or append the bod.php part, either way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to write at beginning of file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760525/need-to-write-at-beginning-of-file-with-php)

Comment: it is not  that i can not write to a file. it is that the code `<?php include "../head.php" ?>`  does not appear in the file. how would prepending make a difference?

Comment: "not that i can not write to a file"  "it is that the code  .. does not appear in the file" sorry they seem to contradict, I'm totally lost.